# SQL select entries from table where atribute equals parameter else select * entries

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql

It is possible in SQL (ORACLE) to select all entry from a table where an atribute equals an parameter and if not select all the others entries?

like in this example:

COD | Name
1   | Monday
2   | Thursday
3   | Saturday

parameter=3

when cod equals parameter(cod=3) return entry of cod parameter(cod=3) (including cod and name)
else
return all others entries different from parameter(cod=3) (including cod and name) (like 1 Monday and 2 Thursday)

Is it possible with SQL (oracle), or i need something like PLSQL?

Comment: Please show the query you tried, the result it returned based on your sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: What is the expected output from the query?

Comment: i write the expected output, and the Bacon Bits got it and solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a correlated query and a non-correlated query:

```
SELECT COD, NAME 
FROM TABLE a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE b WHERE b.COD = a.COD AND b.COD = 3)
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE c WHERE c.COD = 3)
```

I'm not sure if I'm following your logic, entirely, however.

And, actually, in cases where it's all from one table it can be simplified to just:

```
SELECT COD, NAME 
FROM TABLE a
WHERE a.COD = 3
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE c WHERE c.COD = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Bacon Bits, this is what i wanted :)

Comment: seems to me all solved so i close question, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE COD=3)
THEN
  SELECT COD, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE COD=3
ELSE 
  SELECT COD, NAME FROM TABLE
END IF
```

Comment: ??  The question was "Is this possible with SQL" - did you see that?

Comment: @mathguy fairly sure that was added after I read the question.  But valid point.